# adding extra header to the table and wrap it to headers

Tags: r

I have a function which creating a table like below and i want to add one more header to the table and merger the header at the first column.

i want to export this table to excel thats why looking for another solution , tried with flextable already

```
tbl_summmary <-
  tibble(
    outcome = c("A (%)", "B (%)", "C (%)", "D (%)", "Total (n)"),
    group_1 = c(.25, .25, .125, .325, 10),
    group_2 = c(.50, 0.0, .325, .125, 20),
    group_3 = c(.10, .40, .125, .325, 40))

tbl_summmary %>% as.data.frame()
```

output should be look like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `gt` package you're looking to add a spanning column label. Some packages refer to these simply as header rows.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

tbl_summary <-
  tibble(
    outcome = c("A (%)", "B (%)", "C (%)", "D (%)", "Total (n)"),
    group_1 = c(.25, .25, .125, .325, 10),
    group_2 = c(.50, 0.0, .325, .125, 20),
    group_3 = c(.10, .40, .125, .325, 40))

tbl_summary %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = 'Table',
    columns = c(group_1, group_2, group_3)
  )
```

```html
<div id="ipsjipkqip" style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:auto;width:auto;height:auto;">
<style>html {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Helvetica Neue', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: auto;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-color: #A8A8A8;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #A8A8A8;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_heading {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_caption {
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_title {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 125%;
  font-weight: initial;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_subtitle {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 85%;
  font-weight: initial;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top-width: 0;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_bottom_border {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_col_headings {
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_col_heading {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: inherit;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_column_spanner_outer {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: inherit;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_column_spanner_outer:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_column_spanner_outer:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_column_spanner {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_group_heading {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: initial;
  text-transform: inherit;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_empty_group_heading {
  padding: 0.5px;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: initial;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_from_md > :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_from_md > :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_row {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_stub {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: initial;
  text-transform: inherit;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_stub_row_group {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: initial;
  text-transform: inherit;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_row_group_first td {
  border-top-width: 2px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_summary_row {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: inherit;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_first_summary_row {
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_first_summary_row.thick {
  border-top-width: 2px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_last_summary_row {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_grand_summary_row {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-transform: inherit;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_first_grand_summary_row {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  border-top-style: double;
  border-top-width: 6px;
  border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_striped {
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.05);
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_table_body {
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_footnotes {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_footnote {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_sourcenotes {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-left-style: none;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-left-color: #D3D3D3;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-right-color: #D3D3D3;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_sourcenote {
  font-size: 90%;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_left {
  text-align: left;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_center {
  text-align: center;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_right {
  text-align: right;
  font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_font_normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_font_bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_font_italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_super {
  font-size: 65%;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_footnote_marks {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 75%;
  vertical-align: 0.4em;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_asterisk {
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: 0;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_indent_1 {
  text-indent: 5px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_indent_2 {
  text-indent: 10px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_indent_3 {
  text-indent: 15px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_indent_4 {
  text-indent: 20px;
}

#ipsjipkqip .gt_indent_5 {
  text-indent: 25px;
}
</style>
<table class="gt_table">
  
  <thead class="gt_col_headings">
    <tr>
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_left" rowspan="2" colspan="1" scope="col" id="outcome">outcome</th>
      <th class="gt_center gt_columns_top_border gt_column_spanner_outer" rowspan="1" colspan="3" scope="colgroup" id="Table">
        <span class="gt_column_spanner">Table</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_right" rowspan="1" colspan="1" scope="col" id="group_1">group_1</th>
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_right" rowspan="1" colspan="1" scope="col" id="group_2">group_2</th>
      <th class="gt_col_heading gt_columns_bottom_border gt_right" rowspan="1" colspan="1" scope="col" id="group_3">group_3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="gt_table_body">
    <tr><td headers="outcome" class="gt_row gt_left">A (%)</td>
<td headers="group_1" class="gt_row gt_right">0.250</td>
<td headers="group_2" class="gt_row gt_right">0.500</td>
<td headers="group_3" class="gt_row gt_right">0.100</td></tr>
    <tr><td headers="outcome" class="gt_row gt_left">B (%)</td>
<td headers="group_1" class="gt_row gt_right">0.250</td>
<td headers="group_2" class="gt_row gt_right">0.000</td>
<td headers="group_3" class="gt_row gt_right">0.400</td></tr>
    <tr><td headers="outcome" class="gt_row gt_left">C (%)</td>
<td headers="group_1" class="gt_row gt_right">0.125</td>
<td headers="group_2" class="gt_row gt_right">0.325</td>
<td headers="group_3" class="gt_row gt_right">0.125</td></tr>
    <tr><td headers="outcome" class="gt_row gt_left">D (%)</td>
<td headers="group_1" class="gt_row gt_right">0.325</td>
<td headers="group_2" class="gt_row gt_right">0.125</td>
<td headers="group_3" class="gt_row gt_right">0.325</td></tr>
    <tr><td headers="outcome" class="gt_row gt_left">Total (n)</td>
<td headers="group_1" class="gt_row gt_right">10.000</td>
<td headers="group_2" class="gt_row gt_right">20.000</td>
<td headers="group_3" class="gt_row gt_right">40.000</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  
  
</table>
</div>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>